# Text inside a select tag is vertically misaligned

Tags: html, css, html-select

I have a select tag and when there is a value in it it is vertically aligned to the bottom. I checked the CSS on it and it is the only thing is a font size and font. When I remove the doctype from the page everything looks okay, but I am assuming that this happens because the browser corrects it. This problem only occurs on IE8.

Comment: could you please post some code and maybe also link to a sample. Would help us a lot ;)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net is a good place to post your code and post the link here for someone to experiment with..

Comment: If you remove the DOCTYPE IE backs down into quirksmode, which always means trouble at some point. Add the DOCTYPE again and post the code used here for us to have a look at.

Comment: Do you have any non-Latin (e.g. Arabic, Hindi, Thai, etc) text displayed in your `<select>` element? That can cause this kind of problem.

Comment: There is so much code interwoven together that I don't think I can post it. For all intents and purposes it is just a regular select tag with some font css. I can't recreate the problem. I am really just looking for other people who might have encountered the same thing and were able to fix it. Thanks for giving this your consideration.

@David There are no non-Latin characters. The one I was looking at was a select of A, B, C, D, and E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the cause of this issue. In IE8 it stems from the fact that I was applying the same style to a select tag twice. Once in a class it inherited from and once for all select tags.